# How get marker position on dragend in React (google-map-react )

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

Hello Guys how can I get the coordinates (Long and lat ) on the `dragend`-event when I put the marker on the map? I'm using [google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) to render the Map currently
Thanks

This is the Marker Component I currently want to render:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

const Marker = ({ text }) => (
  <div style={{ width: "20px", height: "20px", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    {text}
  </div>
);
```

Im using this component to render the map.

```
const Address = () => {
  //Setup Map Marker
  const [Markers, setMarker] = useState({
    name: "Current position",
    position: {
      lat: 37.77,
      lng: -122.42,
    },
  });
  const renderMarkers = (map, maps) => {
    console.log(maps);
    console.log(map);
    let marker = new maps.Marker({
      position: Markers.position,
      zoom: Markers.zoom,
      draggable: true,
      dragend: (e) => console.log(e),
      map,
      title: "Hello World!",
    });
    return marker;
  };

  return (
    <div className="Address">
      {/* Delivery Section  */}
      <div className="delivery active">
        deleviery
        <div style={{ height: "50vh", width: "100%" }}>
          <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "xxxxxxxx" }}
            defaultCenter={Markers.position}
            defaultZoom={11}
            yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
            onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => renderMarkers(map, maps)}
            // onChildMouseUp={onCircleInteraction3}
            // onDragEnd={(e) => onMarkerDragEnd(e.nativeEvent)}
            // onClick = {changeMarkerPosition}
          ></GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Address;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 3 packages helped me (react-google-maps / react-geocode /react-google-autocomplete)
Hopes this helps anyone wants help to using google maps in react js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, withScriptjs, InfoWindow, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete';

const { MarkerWithLabel } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerWithLabel");


Geocode.setApiKey("xxxxxxxx");
Geocode.enableDebug();

class LocationSearchModal extends React.Component {

    state = {
        address: '',
        city: '',
        area: '',
        state: '',
        zoom: 15,
        height: 200,
        mapPosition: {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0,
        },
        markerPosition: {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0,
        },
        Building:'',
        pincode:''
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                this.setState({
                    mapPosition: {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude,
                    },
                    markerPosition: {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude,
                    }
                },
                    () => {
                        Geocode.fromLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude).then(
                            response => {
                                console.log(response)
                                const address = response.results[0].formatted_address,
                                    addressArray = response.results[0].address_components,
                                    city = this.getCity(addressArray),
                                    area = this.getArea(addressArray),
                                    state = this.getState(addressArray);
                                console.log('city', city, area, state);
                                this.setState({
                                    address: (address) ? address : '',
                                    area: (area) ? area : '',
                                    city: (city) ? city : '',
                                    state: (state) ? state : '',
                                })
                            },
                            error => {
                                console.error(error);
                            }
                        );

                    })
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser!");
        }
    };

    // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    //     if (
    //         this.state.markerPosition.lat !== this.state.center.lat ||
    //         this.state.address !== nextState.address ||
    //         this.state.city !== nextState.city ||
    //         this.state.area !== nextState.area ||
    //         this.state.state !== nextState.state
    //     ) {
    //         return true
    //     } else if (this.state.mapPosition.lat === nextState.mapPosition.lat) {
    //         return false
    //     }
    // }

    getCity = (addressArray) => {
        let city = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
            if (addressArray[i].types[0] && 'administrative_area_level_2' === addressArray[i].types[0]) {
                city = addressArray[i].long_name;
                return city;
            }
        }
    };

    getArea = (addressArray) => {
        let area = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
            if (addressArray[i].types[0]) {
                for (let j = 0; j < addressArray[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if ('sublocality_level_1' === addressArray[i].types[j] || 'locality' === addressArray[i].types[j]) {
                        area = addressArray[i].long_name;
                        return area;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    getState = (addressArray) => {
        let state = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
                if (addressArray[i].types[0] && 'administrative_area_level_1' === addressArray[i].types[0]) {
                    state = addressArray[i].long_name;
                    return state;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    onChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        console.log('Changed ');
    };

    onInfoWindowClose = (event) => { };

    onMarkerDragEnd = (event) => {
        let newLat = event.latLng.lat(),
            newLng = event.latLng.lng();

        Geocode.fromLatLng(newLat, newLng).then(
            response => {
                const address = response.results[0].formatted_address,
                    addressArray = response.results[0].address_components,
                    city = this.getCity(addressArray),
                    area = this.getArea(addressArray),
                    state = this.getState(addressArray);
                this.setState({
                    address: (address) ? address : '',
                    area: (area) ? area : '',
                    city: (city) ? city : '',
                    state: (state) ? state : '',
                    markerPosition: {
                        lat: newLat,
                        lng: newLng
                    },
                    mapPosition: {
                        lat: newLat,
                        lng: newLng
                    },
                })
            },
            error => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    };

    onPlaceSelected = (place) => {
        console.log('place Selected')
        const address = place.formatted_address,
            addressArray = place.address_components,
            city = this.getCity(addressArray),
            area = this.getArea(addressArray),
            state = this.getState(addressArray),
            latValue = place.geometry.location.lat(),
            lngValue = place.geometry.location.lng();

        console.log('latvalue', latValue)
        console.log('lngValue', lngValue)

        // Set these values in the state.
        this.setState({
            address: (address) ? address : '',
            area: (area) ? area : '',
            city: (city) ? city : '',
            state: (state) ? state : '',
            markerPosition: {
                lat: latValue,
                lng: lngValue
            },
            mapPosition: {
                lat: latValue,
                lng: lngValue
            },
        })
    };

    // const AsyncMap = compose(
    //     withProps({
    //         googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyALVjLwOIM1gf7EzdJJVmWLKdLP-yZGTcw&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    //         loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    //         containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    //         mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    //     }),
    //     withScriptjs,
    //     withGoogleMap
    // )((props) =>
    //     <GoogleMap

    render() {
        const AsyncMap = withScriptjs(
            withGoogleMap(
                props => (
                    <GoogleMap
                        defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
                        defaultCenter={{ lat: this.state.mapPosition.lat, lng: this.state.mapPosition.lng }}
                    >
                        {/* InfoWindow on top of marker */}

                        {/*Marker*/}
                        <Marker
                            google={this.props.google}
                            name={'Dolores park'}
                            draggable={true}
                            onDragEnd={this.onMarkerDragEnd}
                            position={{ lat: this.state.markerPosition.lat, lng: this.state.markerPosition.lng }}
                        />
                        <InfoWindow
                            onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
                            position={{ lat: (this.state.markerPosition.lat + 0.0018), lng: this.state.markerPosition.lng }}
                        >
                            <div>
                                <span style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}>{this.state.address}</span>
                            </div>
                        </InfoWindow>
                        <Marker />

                        {/* <MarkerWithLabel
                            position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
                            labelAnchor={new google.maps.Point(0, 0)}
                            labelStyle={{ backgroundColor: "yellow", fontSize: "32px", padding: "16px" }}
                        >
                            <div>Hello There!</div>
                        </MarkerWithLabel> */}


                        {/* For Auto complete Search Box */}
                        <Autocomplete
                            style={{
                                width: '100%',
                                height: '40px',
                                paddingLeft: '16px',
                                marginTop: '2px',
                                marginBottom: '2rem'
                            }}
                            onPlaceSelected={this.onPlaceSelected}
                            types={['(regions)']}
                        />
                    </GoogleMap>
                )
            )
        );

        return (
            <div>
            <AsyncMap
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx&libraries=places"
                    loadingElement={
                        <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
                    }
                    containerElement={
                        <div style={{ height: this.state.height }} />
                    }
                    mapElement={
                        <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
                    }
                />
                <div className='row mt-5 p-2'>
                    <div className="form-group col-12">
                        <label htmlFor="">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" className="form-control" onChange={ this.onChange } readOnly="readOnly" value={ this.state.address }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                        <label htmlFor="">City</label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" className="form-control" onChange={ this.onChange } readOnly="readOnly" value={ this.state.city }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                        <label htmlFor="">Area</label>
                        <input type="text" name="area" className="form-control" onChange={ this.onChange } readOnly="readOnly" value={ this.state.area }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                        <label htmlFor="">State</label>
                        <input type="text" name="state" className="form-control" onChange={ this.onChange } readOnly="readOnly" value={ this.state.state }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                        <label htmlFor="">Building</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Building" className="form-control" onChange={ this.onChange } value={ this.state.Building }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                        <label htmlFor="">pincode</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pincode" className="form-control" onChange={ this.onChange } value={ this.state.pincode }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group d-none">
                        <input type="text" name="city" className="form-control" onChange={ this.props.getData(this.state) } readOnly="readOnly" value={ this.state.mapPosition.lng }/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default LocationSearchModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

`marker.latitude, marker.longitude` see the following example:

```
<GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: 29.5, lng: -95 }}>
      {props.markers.map(marker => {
        const onClick = props.onClick.bind(this, marker)
        return (
          <Marker
            key={marker.id}
            onClick={onClick}
            position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
          >
            ....
          </Marker>
        )
      })}
    </GoogleMap>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks :D , dude I figured it out